# How to use vim as less -R?

Tags: bash, vim, pipe, heredoc

I use the heredoc in vim to go through the output of some command (by pipe-ing output of command). ie.,

```
$ command | vim -
```

But when use `grep` with `--color=always` and pipe to `vim -`, I get the annoying terminal syntax highlighting characters all over the screen. I can still get the right results with `less` command. ie.,

```
$ grep <pattern-file-and-all> --color=always | less -R
```

Can the same thing be done using `vim -` instead of `less -R`?

Comment: What's wrong with `less -R`?

Comment: It sounds like you're opening vim which has syntax highlighting on by default. Have you tried putting syntax off in your vimrc or trying `command | vim -c 'syn on' -` ? I can't replicate your issue either way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvim%5D+%22less+-R%22

Comment: the `vim -c 'syn on' -` didn't work.

Comment: Is plugin the only solution we have as of now?